# How to get friday last week in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to get friday last week  ?

I have tried code the folllowing, but it not forward not backward.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()) - ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) - 4) % 7), '%Y-%m-%d') last_friday;
```

The result that i need should be: 2013-05-24 not 2013-05-31.

Please change my coding.

Comment: I am getting 2013-05-25 in Mysql DB. Probably the calculation part needs attention.

Comment: why i get 2013-05-31 in mydb?

Comment: Result is 2013-05-25 [5.0.51b-community-nt-log]

Comment: Is your server clock correct?

Comment: 2013-05-25, last Saturday it shows

Comment: now, on my pc 2013-05-27, Friday last week not Friday next week.

Answer (score 11):

Dude, try this one:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ((7 + WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) - 4) % 7) DAY), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: I gave a +1 simply because you said dude.

Comment: @JosephCho haha thanks dude! Does this count for another +1?

Answer (score 10):

In MySQL, the [`WEEKDAY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function returns an integer from 0 to 6: 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday etc. If you take that value as the number of days and subtract it from the current date, i.e. like this:

```
NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY
```

you will always get the current [ISO] week's Monday.

Knowing that, you will only need to subtract 3 more days to get the last week's Friday. So, the final expression would go like this:

```
NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) + 3 DAY
```

You can take a look at [this SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/13146) as well.

Comment: This can also be accomplished using the `DAYOFWEEK` function which is 1 based and starts on Sunday.

`DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(curdate()) + 1 DAY)`

Comment: Yes, DAYOFWEEK is more appropriate if the first day of the week is Sunday, while WEEKDAY would work for weeks starting on Monday.

Comment: Your explanation is highly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
SELECT date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL  
CASE weekday(curdate()) -- weekday will give you the index of the day ( 0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, 2 = Wednesday, ... 6 = Sunday)  
WHEN 0 THEN 3 -- If Monday then sub 3 days  
WHEN 6 THEN 2 -- If Sunday then sub 2 days  
ELSE 1 -- Else sub 1 day  
END DAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If on Friday you want last Friday, on Saturday you want yesterday

```
select now() - interval (weekday( now())+ 2)% 7+ 1 day 'Previous Friday';
```

I was likewise looking for a solution for accounting, where I need a full Friday of data. So if today is Friday, then I need `now()- interval 7 day`. However, I may get excited and want to run the query on Saturday, and would expect `now()- interval 1 day`. In view of this, the interval should always be between 1 and 7 in my case. I looked at all previous answers, however for me they did not quite meet my needs. Here is a chart showing each person's "subtract interval" for each possible weekday (0= Monday):

```
+---------+---------+------+----------+------+-----------+
| weekday |    mine | KaeL | Andriy M | dArc | dquinonez |
+---------+---------+------+----------+------+-----------+
|       0 |       3 |    3 |        3 |    3 |         3 |
|       1 |       4 |    4 |        4 |    4 |         1 |
|       2 |       5 |    5 |        5 |    5 |         1 |
|       3 |       6 |    6 |        6 |    6 |         1 |
|       4 |       7 |    0 |        7 |    7 |         1 |
|       5 |       1 |    1 |        8 |    8 |         1 |
|       6 |       2 |    2 |        9 |    9 |         2 |
+---------+---------+------+----------+------+-----------+

mysql> select i 'weekday',
  (i+ 2)% 7+ 1 'mine',
  ((7+ i- 4)% 7) 'KaeL',
  i+ 3 'Andriy M',
  ((7+ i- 4)% 14) 'dArc',
  case i when 0 then 3 when 6 then 2 else 1 end 'dquinonez'
from (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3
  union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 ) q;
```

- 'Kael' stays on today when today is Friday (you may want that.)
- 'Andriy M' and 'dArc' go back 2 Fridays on Saturday and Sunday (which is good if you don't want to look at last Friday until the weekend has past.) Also 'dArc' gives the last Friday of the month using 'last_day', which the original post was using, so this may have been what the original question actually was.
- 'dquinonez' works for me on Sat, Sun, and Mon - which is good if I know I will be running the query on those days only. His method is also the most readable when filled out with the other days - and easiest to modify for special cases.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()) - ((7 + WEEKDAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) - 4) % 14), '%Y-%m-%d') last_friday;
```